# When you flag your first post you can't enter to your flag summary page

Tags: support, flags

Immediately after you flag your first post you can't enter to your flag summary page. And at this moment you have 1 flagged post, even if nobody has reviewed your flag.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it shows after your first *helpful* flag.

Comment: Yes but why? If you have one flag post?

Comment: I wasn't saying it was good. I was just trying to clarify the facts. That's why it's only a comment. :)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256371/0-helpful-flags-doesnt-mean-i-havent-flagged-at-all-please-fix-it-finally (despite of being a dupe, asked after the design update).

Comment: Retagging this as [tag:support] because this is (currently) the intended behavior, and the corresponding feature request is already on MSE, as James points out in his answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you don't have any "helpful" flags *specifically* then there is no link shown in your profile.

You can use the following link until you have a helpful flag, after which there will be a link in your profile:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/current

---

If you want to get it changed, there's already a feature request on MSE, where you can discuss, upvote, add a bounty, etc :):

[If I have flagged a post, show me a "flags" link in my profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199414/if-i-have-flagged-a-post-show-me-a-flags-link-in-my-profile)

Comment: yes but you can have a declined flag in your summary, I think that you must see your summary

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer I'm not disagreeing, etc, just providing the facts - you need to tell the powers that be, in the feature request :)

Comment: thanks for your info, I see the feature request